# How to save a file in .rtf format

Tags: java, swing, file-io, rtf, jfilechooser

I'm using an JFileChooser to make a save function.
But I want to save my files in a .rtf format how do I do this?

My code right now is:

```
@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        JFileChooser saveFile = new JFileChooser();
        int option = saveFile.showSaveDialog(null);
        saveFile.setDialogTitle("Save the file...");
//      saveFile.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Text Files", "txt", "rtf"));

        if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            try {
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(saveFile.getSelectedFile().getPath()));
                writer.write(text);
                writer.close();

            } catch (IOException ex) {

                ex.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Failed to save the file");
            }
        }
    }//End of method
}//End of inner class
```

So I need to implement a code for saving the file into a .rtf

Comment: What is the origin of `text` in `writer.write(text);`?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Its just a instance varible.    JEditorPane editorPane = new JEditorPane();
  scrollPane.setViewportView(editorPane);
  text = editorPane.getText();

Comment: Don't put code in comments.  Instead [edit it into the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14981115/edit).

Comment: http://pastebin.com/uaBSt95U

Comment: Don't put code at external links either.  Links become broken, and many people cannot or will not follow them.  If short enough, paste the code as an edit to the question.  If not, shorten it and GOTO previous sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Presuming (in the absence of an SSCCE) that the `JEditorPane` is already set to `text/rtf` and contains some formatted text, the easiest way to serialize it is:

```
editorPane.write( writer );
```

See [`JTextComponent.write(Writer)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#write%28java.io.Writer%29) for details.